# List comprehension and flattening deep data structure

Tags: python, list-comprehension, flatten

Lets say I have a data structure that looks like the following (this is greatly simplified, my actual data has a significant amount of day-specific data for each job on each date):

```
data = {
    '2019-01-01': {
        'job-1-id': {'name': 'Job 1', 'address': '123 main st.'},
        'job-2-id': {'name': 'Job 2', 'address': '824 1st Ave.'},
    },
    '2019-01-02': {
        'job-1-id': {'name': 'Job 1', 'address': '123 main st.'},
        'job-3-id': {'name': 'Job 3', 'address': '485 Pleasant Rd.'}
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is flatten this, pushing the `date` and `job id` to an array of objects.  E.g.:

```
data_flat = [
    {'id': 'job-1-id', 'date': '2019-01-01', 'name': 'Job 1', 'address': '123 main st.'},
    {'id': 'job-2-id', 'date': '2019-01-01', 'name': 'Job 2', 'address': '824 1st Ave.'},
    {'id': 'job-1-id', 'date': '2019-01-02', 'name': 'Job 1', 'address': '123 main st.'},
    {'id': 'job-3-id', 'date': '2019-01-02', 'name': 'Job 3', 'address': '485 Pleasant Rd.'},
]
```

Obviously I can look over and build a new array:

```
data_flat = []
for date, jobs in data.items():
    for job_id, job in jobs.items():
        data_flat.append({'id': job_id, 'date': date, etc...})
```

But is there a more pythonic/efficient way to do this using list comprehension with nested data like this?  About all I can think of is using list comprehension for the inner loop, and then instead of appending, using `extend` to build the list.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible list comprehension solution might be as follows, where we unpack `job` dictionary and add `id` and `date` key-value pair to it, while iterating over the two for loops

```
[{**job, 'id': job_id, 'date': date} for date, jobs in data.items() for job_id, job in jobs.items()]
```

Which in traditional for-loop, looks like

```
for date, jobs in data.items():
    for job_id, job in jobs.items():
        data_flat.append({**job, 'id': job_id, 'date': date})
```

Answer (score 0):

### flat list can be made through `reduce` easily.

All you need to use *initializer* - third argument in the `reduce` function.

```py
reduce(
 lambda _list, date: _list.extend(
   {'date': date, 'id':_id, **detail} for _id, detail in data[date].items()) or _list, 
 data, 
 [])
```

Above code works for both python2 and python3, but you need to import reduce module as `from functools import reduce`. Refer below link for details.

- [for python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce)
- [for python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)